# Aptana 3.04, insert comment when typing h1?

Tags: css, insert, aptana

Every time I try to type "h1" w/o quotes in a CSS file Aptana is inserting a comment snippet. It did not do this in past versions, please change the auto-complete to something else as you can imagine having to type h (escape) 1 just to style a head tag can be quite frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm it is doing it for me too on the latest version. Also, is this a question or are you dispensing some advice? If the latter, please phrase it as a question and then answer it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This is being worked on, but in the meantime:

1. Commands > Source > Edit this bundle
2. Open command/insert_source_header.rb and edit/delete the cmd.trigger = 'head' line
3. Save the file